# ООП: автоматическое присвоение имени объектам

Tags: java, ооп

Вопрос больше концептуальный, но если Вы хотите привести пример в ответе, то можете это сделать на языке `Java`.

Не получилось сформулировать проблему на общем уровне, потому сформулирую на классической задаче рисования фигур:

- Каждая фигура может быть нарисована, стёрта, перемещена и отмасштабирована. Как раз тот случай, когда имеет смысл создавать абстрактный класс и прописать в нём все эти методы.
- Каждой фигуре соответствует собственный класс, унаследованный от абстрактного.
- При создании фигуры создаётся новый экземпляр объекта по формуле `<имя фигуры> + <номер>`, например `triangle1`, `triangle2`, `circle3` и т. д.

Вопрос такой: а как, собственно, сделать автоматическое именование этих фигур при создании? Мы же не можем написать что-то вроде

```
Triangle triangle+Triangle:getCount() = new Triangle(args[]);
```

где `:getCount()` - статический метод, возвращающий уже преобразованное в строку число созданных фигур данного типа.

Comment: Автоматическое именования вам и не нужно. Просто поместите все объекты в список. Их индекс в списке заменит вам число в имени. Ну или Map используйте. А вот кодогенерация вам вряд ли нужна

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос - нужны ли вам эти имена вообще?

Если сами имена не принципиальны, а нужно лишь как-то хранить все объекты, то помещайте созданные объекты в список (или другую, аналогичную структуру), он как раз для этого и создан. Можете итерировать, сортировать и т.п.

Если же вам нужны именно имена (т.е. вы будете перемещать объекты в списке и/или между списками), то пропишите в конструкторе, что имя объекта = его тип + авто-возрастающий номер, и храните это в поле объекта. Авто-возрастающий номер можно хранить в глобальной переменной (не совсем хорошо), или (лучше) в Фабрике, которая будет заниматься созданием ваших объектов.

Кстати, почему вы говорите, что *"Мы же не можем написать ... статический метод, возвращающий уже преобразованное в строку число созданных фигур данного типа"*. Можем, это тоже вариант решения.

---

Любое решение (из описанных выше, или другое) будет продиктовано более конкретными требованиями предъявляемыми к нему.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. Проблема в том, что надо как-то обращаться к объектам после того, как они созданы. Например если мы выделили мышью нарисованный треугольник, чтобы далее что-то с ним сделать, нам надо чтобы на уровне кода произошло обращение к соответствующему объекту. Тут-то я и не понимаю, как можно обойтись без уникального имени переменной-объекта.

Comment: В этом примере, вам нужна структура в которой будут все объекты (список, quad-дерево, и т.п.). Метод в структуре, который найдет объект по координатам клика. И сам объект, со своим именем.

Comment: Хорошо, ещё раз спасибо. И последний добавочный вопрос, вернее, просьба: Вы бы не могли показать пример обращения к объекту по имени в той концепции, что вы описали выше? Если я правильно Вас понял, то там имя переменной и имя объекта - не одно и то же.

Comment: У объекта лежащего в массиве, нет отдельного "имени переменной". Обычно делается так, чтобы имя объекта хранилось в самом объекте (в виде строки). Тогда объект можно перемещать между списками, менять его положение в списке, и это никак не "испортит" его имя.

Comment: Для обращения к объекту по имени (что вам обычно не понадобится), вы можете написать метод GetObjectByName(name string). Обычно же вам нужно будет получать объект по его координатам, попаданию под курсор, выбору из списка в GUI, аналогичными GetObjectByXxxxx(). Все эти методу будут перебирать список объектов (массив, мар, дерево, или другую структуру хранения которую вы выберете) в поисках совпадений.